# How to (make a ) scale for C# in a panel?

Tags: c#, scale, panel, mandelbrot

Hi im new to c# and I am trying to learn how to (make a) scale in a panel. I have created a Mandelbrot, but now I have to zoom in on -2 to 2 in both axes.

My question is, how do I make a scale (e.g x,y 0.01) for this panel in which I can choose the center of the panel myself? I want my graph to go from -2 to 2 in both axes. I know I should be using Graphics.ScaleTransform to scale it and e.Graphics.TranslateTransform to center it, but I just can't figure out how.

This is my panel method :

```
public void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
            
            for (double p = 0; p < 400; p++)
                {
                    for (double j = 0; j < 400; j++)
//over here I zoomed it in manually, but it was just to make sure the Mandelbrot was working
                    { 
                        int mandel = mandelgetalberekening((p - 200)*0.01, (j-200)*0.01);
                        if (mandel % 2 == 0)

                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Purple, (float)p, (float)j, 1, 1);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, (float)p, (float)j, 1, 1);
                        }
                    }

                }
```

and if I try to use something like this I just gives me an empty window:

```
public void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform((float)0.01, (float)0.01);



            for (double p = 0; p < 400; p++)
                {
                    for (double j = 0; j < 400; j++)
                    {
                        int mandel = mandelgetalberekening((p - 200)*0.01, (j-200)*0.01);
                        if (mandel % 2 == 0)

                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Purple, (float)p, (float)j, 1, 1);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, (float)p, (float)j, 1, 1);
                        }
                    }

                }
``
```

Comment: Drawing pixels with rectangles ;-) I don't see any TranslateTransform calls?

Comment: If this is about Windows Forms, please add the "winforms" tag. There are lots of other UI frameworks out there...